# How do I add my own function to work with the methods in the previously intalled package in R

Tags: r

I am working with `rEMM` package and want to add a function that is very similar to `fade`.

A little background: this function is 'fading' data stream based on the temporal structure of the data. The weights are calculated as `w = 2^{-lambda t}`. I would like to only modify the weights for this method to `1/(1+(T-t/c)^lambda)`. In this case I have two additional parameters I would have to pass to the new function: `T` and `c` compare to the original `fade` function. 
It seems that the only difference between current script `fade.R` would be the lines 24-30, where I would create new `lambda_factor`.

I have absolutely no idea how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you wish to modify the package itself, or are you happy to just have a `fade` function that does what you specify?

Comment: I don't really wish to modify the package, but probably just have a wrapper on that function.

Answer (score 4):

The author of `fade` seems to have exposed `lambda` as a parameter that you can specify. Looking at the code with `showMethods(fade, includeDef=TRUE)`, everything ends up at `rEMM:::.fade`, where we see

```
> rEMM:::.fade
function (x, t = 1, lambda = NULL) 
{
    if (is.null(lambda)) 
        lambda_factor <- x@tnn_d$lambda_factor
    else lambda_factor <- 2^(-lambda)
    x@tnn_d$counts <- x@tnn_d$counts * lambda_factor^t
    x@tracds_d$mm <- smc_fade(x@tracds_d$mm, lambda_factor^t)
    invisible(x)
}
<environment: namespace:rEMM>
```

So instead of writing a new function, why not calculate `lambda` the way you'd like it, transformed so that `lambda_factor` used in this function is consistent with the transformations

```
mylambda <- function(t, lambda, T, c)
    -log(1/(1+(T-t/c)^lambda)), 2) / t
```

and then invoke `fade` as

```
fade(x, t, mylambda(t, lambda, T, c))
```

? Wrap this further as

```
myfade <- function(x, t, lambda)
    fade(x, t, mylambda(t, lambda, T, c))
```

Comment: Hi Matrin, This is very close, however, the author uses exponential function for fading, `f = 2^{-lambda*t}`, and I wish to replace this function completely. In this case, modifying lambda would not do the trick, as I have to modify the function itself (new fading function is no longer exponential but rather sigmoid), so I would not have `lambda_factor^t` when changing `x@tnn_d$counts`

Comment: My intention was to solve 2 ^(-lambda_0 t) == 1 / (1 + (T - t / c)^lambda) --> lambda_0 = -log_2(1 / (1 + (T - t/c)^lambda)) / t so that the body of the function does not need changing.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the code for the current fade function that looks like:

```
fade <- function(...){
  ...
}
```

Just copy that code, make the modifications you want (you seem to know what you want), and then just run the code. Your new function will appear in the global environment, and will be called each time you call fade(...).